# SQL statement MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

```
UPDATE product, 
       claimdetail 
   SET product.ProductQuantity = (product.ProductQuantity - claimdetail.quantity) 
 WHERE product.ProductId =  claimdetail.productcode
```

The code above is to deduct product from stock when staff is use product to claim it have a problem. If the staff use the same product 2 time it deduct only one time, how can I fix it?

Such as `claimdetail` have the product code "4712893150132" in many record it deduct only one record it should deduct all records.

Comment: This is very similar to your last question. Again it is not very comprehensible. Please revise. Maybe provide table schema and sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE product
JOIN
(
SELECT productcode, SUM(quantity) SUMClaim
FROM claimdetail
GROUP BY productcode
) claims on claims.productcode = product.ProductId
SET product.ProductQuantity = product.ProductQuantity - claims.SUMClaim
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE product 
   SET product.ProductQuantity = (product.ProductQuantity - claimdetail.quantity) 
 WHERE product.ProductId =  claimdetail.productcode

Comment: it have a little problem the code can deduct from stock but if it have same claimdetail.productcode it use only the first row to deduct it like I BUY ICECREAM 2 PIECE AND IT PUT INTO 2 RECORD it deduct only one Thank